# Creating .method in ruby

Tags: ruby

How do I create a method that takes as a variable the object that it's called upon...

For example in `"Hello".to_s`, `.to_s` takes `"Hello"` as argument.

EDIT:

Thank you for answering my question!

For anyone wondering how to do this, here's an example:

```
  def double
    self*2
  end

  2.double
  =>4
```

Thanks again

Comment: Why do you want to do that? That totally defeats the purpose of OOP in Ruby.

Comment: I don't know, it's very commonly done.. and I'm curious as to how it's done.

Comment: ...and I don't really see what you mean.

Comment: I don't see what you mean. `"Hello"` is not a variable.

Comment: His question is pretty simple to understand... He just would like to know how "Hello".to_s call the "to_s" method with "Hello" as an argument. The fact that in this case "Hello" is not a "variable" is just not obvious for a newbie to Ruby.

Comment: @ByScripts So according to your interpretation, OP mistook "variable" for "argument"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your exemple, in `to_s` body you can refer to `"Hello"` using `self`. If that's not what you're asking, you need to describe a bit better your problem.

Comment: I believe that this is proper solution. But I also think that @Waseem is right; this defeats purpose of OOP in Ruby.

Comment: This question might be influenced by python, where `self` is the first parameter of any method (if I remember correctly, tell me if I'm wrong).

Comment: Thanks for that. Exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 4):

You need to open the class and extend it.

```
class String
  def i_love
    "I love #{self}"
  end
end

"Pizza".i_love
=> "I love Pizza"
```